# Regex for credit card requiring same repeat symbols

Tags: javascript, regex

I am struggling to find and come up with a regex that disallows inconsistent symbols in credit cards.

```
\d{4}[\s\-]*\d{4}[\s\-]*\d{4}[\s\-]*\d{4}
```

For example, the Regex above allows for the below to pass. The last one is problematic as it contains '-' and ' ' and ''. How do I come up with a regex that requires all the symbols ('-' or ' ' or '') to be consistently the same? i.e. only allow the first 3 but not the last statement.

1234123412341234, 1234-1234-1234-1234, 1234 1234 1234 1234, 1234-12341234 1234

Comment: You're sure you mean `[\s\-]*`, allowing ' - ' or '--'. Maybe you want `[\s\-]?`.

Comment: If you don't want to match a newline and a single space, tab or hyphen `\b\d{4}([ \t-]?)\d{4}\1\d{4}\1\d{4}\b` https://regex101.com/r/sIv8AM/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a capture group to "remember" what the separator was in the first case, and ensure that the other cases also use it.

The final regex is: `\d{4}([\s\-])*\d{4}\1*\d{4}\1*\d{4}`

The `()` around the first `[\s\-]` start the capture group; the `\1` later on indicates to use the same value as was previously captured.

See it in action here https://regexr.com/5l74g

Edit: per the comments, a better solution might be
`\d{4}([\s\-]?)\d{4}\1\d{4}\1\d{4}`, depending on what exactly your requirements are. This one ensures that `-`s and  s are not mixed, and also that there is only 0 or 1 separators.

Comment: the \1* isn't quite right, this way 1234 12341234 1234 slips through

Comment: Fair enough! Depending on the exact behavior you are after, `\d{4}([\s\-]*)\d{4}\1\d{4}\1\d{4}` might be more suitable (`*` inside the group)

Comment: That I wanted to answer, but you were faster :-)

Comment: @Alex Thanks so much! Been trying to find this answer. I think \d{4}([\s\-]*)\d{4}\1\d{4}\1\d{4} is a better answer for credit cards, If I may add, it might be more complete to change the `*` inside the grp to `?`, as the former causes 1234--1234--1234--1234 to be allowed. Cheers :)